# Should I cite the article that I am writing an opinion piece on?

Tags: citations

I am writing an opinion piece on a definite article. Should I cite that article whenever I write about the author's ideas in my opinion paper?

I couldn't find any helpful resources when I googled this query.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with opinion papers, but the natural way to go seems to be the following: find 3 or 4 other opinion papers in the venue you intend to submit to, and see how they did it.

Comment: Could you state the field of your paper?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment saying that you should see other opinion papers in the same venue. I personally think you should - it seems logical. If someone wants to read the original paper, they need some way to be able to know where to find it.